# jQuery is not defined although jQuery is loaded into the page before the calling script

Tags: jquery

I have an html "details" element that serves as my page's table of contents. I'm trying to dynamically rewrite the document's html "title" tag based on the currently "active" element in the TOC (a class="active")

However, although it works in the console, when I actually embed it into the footer of my page, I'm getting a console error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

I'm including jQuery into the footer of my page just before this inline script. Other jquery elements on the page are working fine. What could be the problem with this script?

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var title = jQuery('.myEl').find('a.active').text();
        jQuery('title').text(title);
    });
</script>
```

The HTML for this page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Customer Testimonials (Page 3)</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="screen" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <details class="myEl" open="open"><summary>In this article</summary>
        <ol>
            <li><a href="mypage/">Introduction</a></li>
            <li><a href="mypage/2/" class="active">Title for the second page</a></li>
            <li><a href="mypage/3/">Title for the third page</a></li>
        </ol>
    </details>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts.jquery.js' async='async'></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var title = jQuery('.myEl').find('a.active').text();
        jQuery('title').text(title);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Has the jQuery file definitely been loaded? Your browser console should tell you if not.

Comment: Aside from your initial concerns with jQuery - setting the title tag on the client side does not bode well for SEO.

Comment: Please make a minimal example of a complete page that doesn't work and show that in the question.

Comment: I've updated the question with the html structure of my page.

Comment: @kyle, isn't the web crawler a client? It should be viewing the computed source no?

Comment: @RegEdit Don't count on Google to index your content if you rely on JavaScript to place it on the page (same goes for the title tag). See: http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `async='async'` in the script tag means "don't wait for this script to load, go ahead and proceed with other scripts meanwhile". Remove that part from the tag.

The next problem is that there is no link in a list item with the class `active` so the jQuery selector matches nothing.

Comment: +1 The async was the issue. Thanks for the help. I just left the active class off my question html. Its actually in the markup based on jQuery adding it at runtime.